# jquery in dojo environment: unable to refresh date.picker

Tags: jquery, dojo

Hi I have trouble refreshing jquery.datepicker in the dojo environment.

After getting the json (date and number of tests) by request.post, I forced result json into array object. I call function - "$("#Hour").datepicker("refresh");" and  nothing happened. Please see my code below:-

```
var arrDatesNTests = [];

function checkavailableDates(mydate)
{
     var $return=false;// set all dates disenable 
     var $returnclass ="unavailable";
     $checkdate = $.datepicker.formatDate("yy-mm-dd", mydate);
     for(var i = 0; i < arrDatesNTests.length; i++)
         {    
             if(arrDatesNTests[i] == $checkdate)
             {
                 $return = true;// enable specified dates only
                 $returnclass= "available";
             }
          }
          return [$return,$returnclass];
}

$(function() 
{
    $("#Date").datepicker
    ({
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        onSelect: function( selectedDate ) 
        {
            // later add function for hourpicker
        },
        beforeShowDay: checkavailableDates,
     });
});

on(selectBatches, 'change', function(valueBatch)
{
    window.winBatch = valueBatch;
    pause.show();// cause the main container to be on standby
    request.post('list_dates.php',
    { data:{nameDB : (window.winDB), nameCard : (window.winCard), selectedBatch :  
       valueBatch}, handleAs: "json"
    }).then
    (
        /*//result
        response ={"msg":[
        {"date":"2012-03-26","numTests":"857"},
        {"date":"2012-03-27","numTests":"470"},
        {"date":"2012-03-28","numTests":"544"},
        {"date":"2012-03-29","numTests":"618"}]}
        */

         function(response)
         {   try
          {    if(response.msg)
                 {   
                      arrDatesNTests = (response.msg);
                      $("#Hour").datepicker("refresh");
                      pause.hide();
                 }
                else
                {
                      pause.hide();
                      var errormsg = (response.errmsg +"\r\n"+ response.errcode);
                      throw new Error(errormsg);
                 }
           }

          catch(e)
          {
              pause.hide();
              errDlg(""+e+"");
          }
         }
    )

});
```

Please advise. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here's my jsfiddle link:- http://jsfiddle.net/clementyap/2KHE5/17/ .  As I prodded deeper, I found out that the updated result will be revealed, if I clicked on the arrow button or on any day. Please advise

Comment: Turns out that it is typo error. It should be $("#datehere4").datepicker....

Comment: Well, I am using just Dojo and I am unable to refresh the date picker. Please let me know if you have any solutions for tihs.